# Is there any way to know when was the last PostgreSQL materialised view updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, materialized-views

Need to show a timestamp of the last materialized view updated or synced?

I can think of an approach that will have a table with `started_at` and `completed_at` columns.

Then, before calling the materialized query, we could save `started_at`, and once it completes we can save the `completed_at`.

And to show `last_synced_at` time,  I could use the lastest record with `completed_at`.

Is there any better approach to do this?

I'm using

1. Ruby on Rails
2. PostgresSQL 13.2.
3. [scenic gem](https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic) to update the Materialized View.

Comment: Since you can use functions in the defintion of a materialized view you could just select the current time `SELECT ..., NOW() AS my_timestamp` in the defintion of your view.  Triggers are another potential solution.

Comment: @max So, what you are saying is to add the `my_timestamp` column in the view and save its value as NOW(). This will be added to all the rows in the table?